# Cannot run all JUnit tests at one time

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am unable to run all my JUnit tests at one time for some reason. I am right clicking on my program, selecting "Run As", and "JUnit Test" and it only runs 3 out of 19 test cases. What may be possible reasons for this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: On your sreenshot the performanceShouldProcess5000CharsPerSec test is not finished, though the next test won't process unless this test end.

Comment: lol, isn't it typical that it's the performance test that is having issues :-)